# VS2010 doesnt generates app pool name parameter for msdeploy package

Tags: visual-studio-2010, parameters, msdeploy, application-pool, webdeploy

I'm using VisualStudio 2010 to generate web deploy package for web application.
I have enabled "Include application pool options" in publish settings.

So after building web package on my Windows 7 PC from VS 2010 I get web package with all additional files, and in .SetParameters.xml file there is "IIS Web Application Pool Name" parameter to specify app pool name when deploying package. In package archive.xml file has app pool configurations.

The problem is with Server 2008 R2 build server - when I'm building web package from VS 2010 there is no "IIS Web Application Pool Name" parameter in .SetParameters.xml file but package's archive.xml file has app pool configurations and while deploying web package app pools are created with default names.

The question is -

How it can be that app pool configuration is in package but there is no "IIS Web Application Pool Name" parameter?

Maybe there is something with Msdeploy installation or VS2010 installation on server?

How I can declare this parameter in VS2010?

Comment: What do you mean "When I am building from Windows 7 Pc... & When I am building from Server 2008 R2..."?

Comment: I mean I'm building project using VS2010 on my development PC and all is fine. Then I'm building this project using VS2010 on other machine - and there is no app pool name paramater in generated file.

Comment: Ok, clear enough. Are you sure that you are building your project with the same configuration (where you have set the app pool settings) from the 2nd machine?

Comment: yes, configurations are same. I've simply copied project from my Pc to other Pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally solved this issue.

The problem was with Visual Studio installation - on my development Pc is installed VS 2010 SP1, on other Pc was installed VS2010.

After I've installed VS 2010 SP1 update on other Pc, package was generated correctly and with "IIS Web Application Pool Name" parameter in SetParameters file.